# django template filter

Tags: django, templates

I have this code situation

{% if 1|floatformat in '7,10' %}
   yes
{% else %}
   no
{% endif %}

the return result is always set to "yes", how to make the result return "no"
please help.
thanks

Comment: im sorry i have to clarify that '7,10' is the result from database query which is value is 7,10 (number with separated comma)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to make out from your example what exactly is happening here, because you're substituting dummy data for what's really coming out of the database.

As you've written it, the result will always be "yes" because the string '7,10' contains the string '1'.

It *sounds* like what you're trying to achieve is:

> If this number is in this list, then yes, otherwise no.

So let's rewrite this template to be a little more real:

```
{% if mynumber in yeslist %} yes {% else %} no {% endif %}
```

This assumes that:

- mynumber is a number
- yeslist is a list of numbers

I'm not sure what you're using floatformat for in this case.

If the above assertions aren't true, and you have to use strings, then your work is much harder, and you should be processing yeslist server-side. For example, if yeslist is just a string like "7,10,123,93,9,19,83", then figuring out if the number `8` is in the list will be needlessly difficult in templates. Much easier to do it in your view:

```
def myview(request):
    ctx = {}
    # ... do some work ...
    # yeslist now has a string like "7,10,123,93,9,19,83"
    ctx['yeslist'] = yeslist.split(',')
    # ... do more work, and render the response ...
```

Now, `{% if '8' in yeslist %}` will no longer return a false positive, because it's not doing a substring match, it's doing list membership.

Comment: thanks Idan Gazit, that's exactly what i mean. i will try your solution of this matter. thank you

Comment: Adit: If you found my post helpful, then please upvote or accept it!

Answer (score 0):

`1|floatformat` returns `1` and the condition checks if `1` is in `'7,10'`, since django considers `'7,10'` as a string it returns True. Try passing a list and it will return no